# Need help on Perl Win32::Guitest

Tags: perl

How can I access(connect) a particular wireless network in the "view available networks" window by using `Win32::GuiTest` automation.

This is the view available networks window:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Is it a requirement that you use the Win32::GuiTest module?

If not, [Win32::Wlan](http://search.cpan.org/~corion/Win32-Wlan/lib/Win32/Wlan.pm) will allow you to manage wireless network connections on windows.